# Создание DataSet с нуля с помощью дизайнера. Почему не получается создать связь между таблицами?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Если попытаться создать связь таким образом,
[image: редактор связи между таблицами]

то почему-то коллекция связей остается пустой
[image: вид отладки]

Но, если создавать связь из кода, то связь есть, и с ней можно потом работать
[image: вид отладки когда связь между таблицами есть]

Как всё-таки правильно создать связь с помощью дизайнера?

Comment: Так у вас же стоит радиокнопка на "Только внешний ключ".

Comment: @Anamnian да, и что? Мне как бы связь по внешнему ключу и нужна.

Comment: Ну так и выбирайте первый вариант и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @Anamnian первый вариант - это  "Both Relation..."?

Comment: Именно так. (1 символ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вашем скриншоте вы выбираете только создание ограничений внешнего ключа, что не является созданием связей между таблицами. Вам следует выбрать первое либо последнее значение.

---

**DataRelation**
Основной объект, используемый для представления отношения родителя / дочернего объекта между двумя объектами DataTable.

**ForeignKeyConstraint**
Представляет собой действия, применяемое к набору столбцов в отношении первичного ключа / внешнего ключа, когда значение или строка либо удаляются, либо обновляются.

Объект `DataRelation` может использоваться для создания и принудительного применения `ForeignKeyConstraint`,
который может использоваться для поддержания ссылочной целостности между родительской и дочерней таблицами в наборе данных.
Но создание `DataRelation` не создает автоматически `ForeignKeyConstraint`.

Объект `DataRelation` является более общим термином и может использоваться и для других функций.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.